# return all tthe charecters between two single qutes ' ' in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

i have data like this i read it from a file line by line

```
{0 1,1 1,4 1,6 'text text'}
{0 1,1 1,4 1,5 1,6 'text text text text'}
{0 1,5 1,6 'text texttext text'}
{1 1,6 'text text texttexttext text'}
```

i want to get all the text between the ' ' so i get it like this

```
'text text'
'text text text text'
'text texttext text'
'text text texttexttext text'
```

i tried to use re.sub to remove the first charecters before the '

```
line=re.sub(r'.*\'', '', line)
```

but it removed all the charecters 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
lines = ["{0 1,1 1,4 1,6 'text text'}", 
         "{0 1,1 1,4 1,5 1,6 'text text text text'}",
         "{0 1,5 1,6 'text texttext text'}",
         "{1 1,6 'text text texttexttext text'}"]
for line in lines:
    print(re.sub(r"[^']*('[^']*').*", r"\1", line))
```

and the output:

```
'text text'
'text text text text'
'text texttext text'
'text text texttexttext text'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findall` or `search`

```
value = "{0 1,1 1,4 1,6 'text text'}"    
content = re.search("('.*')", value).group(0)
content # 'text text'
```